# ManyToManyField initialization in Django

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have following model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='random')
    news = models.ForeignKey('News')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True) # ForeignKey('User')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    upvotes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    votes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Vote', related_name='votes_table')


class Vote(models.Model):
    cmt = models.ForeignKey(Comment)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    vote_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0) # vote_type is +1 for upvote & -1 for downvote
```

When a user submits a new comment, I initialize a new one, like this: `c = Comment(uuid=uuid.uuid4(),news=n, user=request.user, text=comment_text)`. Now the problem is, when I print `c.votes.exists()`, it's `True`. How did this comment c have an entry in the `comments_votes` table?

Comment: Did you save the new comment before checking if votes exists?
You can see the generated SQL for the exists() call in a django shell when django is in DEBUG model using
from django.db import connection
print connection.queries[-1]

Answer (score 0):

The generated 'sql': u'SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "auth_user" INNER JOIN "app_vote" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "app_vote"."user_id") WHERE "app_vote"."cmt_id" = 62  LIMIT 1'

As the primary key for Comment is User, c.votes.exists() actually checks if the user has any votes rather than checking if the comment has any votes.

P.S. You can get the comment votes with a query on Vote if you filter by the comment uuid instead of pk